# Simple rsa encryption/decryption in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, rsa

I'd like to generate pair of keys and just type something like:

```
Rsa.Decrypt(data, privateKey); 
Rsa.Encrypt(data, publicKey);
```

Is there any easy way to do this? I know there is something like RsaCryptoServiceProvider but it needs XML to create proper object. I'd like to store private/public key as simple string (not xml) which i'll put in web.config in:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MyPublicKey" value"...."/>
    <add key="MyrivateKey" value"...."/>
</appSettings>
```

And later i'll encrypt web.config so everything will be safe (IIS will deal with it). Is it possible to do that in that way?

Comment: Don't encrypt arbitrary data with RSA. RSA is *very* brittle and needs to be used in the correct way with the correct padding etc. To encrypt arbitrary data you should use a combination of RSA and a block cypher.

Comment: Two questions immediately spring to mind: First, how are you planning on communicating the public key securely to the message recipient? Remember, public key crypto is only as secure as the key management system.  Second, does it not strike you as insanely dangerous to put the *private* key into a well-known file like web.config?  I would be storing my private key in a system specifically designed for sensitive data storage, not just stuffing it into web.config.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: in other words, use a well known standard, such as Cryptographic Message Syntax or PGP (with .net, CMS is probably better supported).
@Eric: as for the private key, if web.config is well secured (and I presume most clients should not have access to it) then it is as good a place as any. If you store it in a secure place, you can be protected against copying, but you'll need to access it from an automated system anyway, so where do you store the access key/password? (for very secure systems you can use a HSM or TPM of course).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create an RSACryptoServiceProvider object with your preferred keys size (512 / 1024 / 2048...):

```
int keySize = 1024;
m_ServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize);
```

Or use the default size:

```
m_ServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
```

Then use ExportParameters to get what you need at byte array, for example to get the Modulus part of the public key use:

```
byte[] publicModulus = m_ServiceProvider.ExportParameters(true).Modulus;
```

I've passed a true value in ExportParameters because you wanted access to the private key parameters.

and then you only need to convert the byte array to string:

```
string publicModulusStr = Convert.ToBase64String(modulus);
```

Later, when you want to read from the web.config and and recreate the RSACryptoServiceProvider object, create an RSAParameters object with the text you stored in the file and then pass the RSAParameters to the RSACryptoServiceProvider constructor.

And just a note: the web.config file you are saving should be kept very private since you store your private keys inside.