# RSA in C# public key is same as private key?

Tags: c#, rsa, public-key, private-key

I searched a lot online but stuck with doubts in RSA public key and private key cryptography.

When I checked [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8z5e11b.aspx) site, I tried this

```
 RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaEncryptDecrypt = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

 byte[] privateKeyByte = rsaEncryptDecrypt.ExportParameters(true).Modulus;
 byte[] publicKeyByte = rsaEncryptDecrypt.ExportParameters(false).Modulus;

 string privateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyByte);
 string publicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(publicKeyByte);
```

The string public key and private key are **Same**!!!
Is it correct? I mean how can the strings be same? Isn't suppose to be two different keys?

Please correct me if I am wrong. I am confused !

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

I mistook the parameters,

But then: When I saw

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592990/simple-rsa-encryption-decryption-in-net#answer-6593054"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592990/simple-rsa-encryption-decryption-in-net#answer-6593054%22)

How can I get string value? because I have to store it in App.config and access it whenever I want. I mean I need to store the public and private keys both in App.config

**UPDATE2**

I am sorry, I just used ToXmlString property of RSACryptoServiceProvider's instance.
Got the private key and public key.

Comment: you just transformed the Modulus! That part is the same for both keys ;) - research a bit on RSA it's not that hard: you can read on the modulus (the N) here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Key_generation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Modulus` is the same for both.

The public key consists of the encryption exponent `e` and the modulus `n`.

Traditionally the decryption key consists of the decryption exponent `d` and the same modulus `n`. For better performance, it often includes some more numbers, such as the prime factors `p` and `q` of `n`.

To better visualize what a public key includes try `ToXmlString(false/true)`

Public key `ToXmlString(false)`:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>4ZpwnuksQkLuqLczu5eJcS6aIFaPsTwGpS57/P9rviJWI7sweYZnE/eBVtPVKoanhgHxmcHyk4GbyvCnXKSzDw==</Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Public Key+Private Key `ToXmlString(true)`:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
     <Modulus>4ZpwnuksQkLuqLczu5eJcS6aIFaPsTwGpS57/P9rviJWI7sweYZnE/eBVtPVKoanhgHxmcHyk4GbyvCnXKSzDw==</Modulus>
     <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
     <P>8lLDYv+MEBUdp0eUY3an4mlU7ovmyV6f60RJoXOB9Hs=</P>
     <Q>7lYYef5/PvPOyrN0HGZPt/RWknfVd4c3Kc6WVEZICX0=</Q>
     <DP>UI3GufAthWMfmm4nG/Fj2dYeD7aeH66/BpyKxYr6VmU=</DP>
     <DQ>sBZkFx30nWo8in5zdtgQZfTcUXLAAIOiOf0sDC+w4XE=</DQ>
     <InverseQ>GBkNq0KZ4ERaEO/oVQoQDONw6ZHixNimR5IJ7cbzKXw=</InverseQ>
     <D>ErLyUrmQ6Y0SqvlEWHAe/DqYm8WQ82e+RUKtFDM3gvK9ygloqftx6rhn9XvM/ji1JnrDqiuepn5T3D3F+3GVQQ==</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Comment: Oh okay got it.. i mistook the parameters. :( ! How can I get string value? because I have to store it in App.config and access it whenever I want. I mean I need to store the public and private keys both in App.config

Comment: I cannot get separate private key into string?

Comment: @NagarajTantri Why do you want the private key without the public key? The only part of the combined private+public key that's not part of the private key is the exponent `e`. And since it often has a standard value, such as `2^16+1`, leaving it out doesn't gain you anything. I'd simply consider the public key as a subset of the private key.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation for [`RSAParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters.aspx) - the public key is formed from `{e, n}` (`Exponent` and `Modulus`). The private key is formed from `{d, n}` (`D` and `Modulus`). so when you call `ExportParameters(false)` you *would* get the same Modulus as that's part of the *public* information - but you won't get a value for the `D` property.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I guess my comment is a good answer after all:

As you only transformed the modulus part of the keys and this part is there in both privat and public key it's no wonder.

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Key_generation